# C++ adding elements of list of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, lambda, stl

I have a vector of pairs of int, and I want to add all the first elements of each pair. I have written following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

#define PII pair<int,int>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int,int>> v;
    v.push_back(PII(1,2));
    v.push_back(PII(3,4));
    v.push_back(PII(5,6));
    cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0,[](auto &a, auto &b){return a.first+b.first;});
    return 0;
}
```

Here it is giving errors http://ideone.com/Kf2i7d.
The required answer is 1+3+5 = 9. I can't understand the errors it is giving.

Comment: I stopped reading at `#define`, why not use a `typedef` instead?

Comment: Or `using PII = std::pair<int,int>;` since it's c++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this call of the algorithm

```
cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0,[](auto &a, auto &b){return a.first+b.first;});
```

its third parameter is initialized by 0 and hence has deduced type `int`.

It corresponds to the accumulator of the algorithm that accumulates the values that are suplied by the second parameter of the lambda expression.

So you have to write

```
cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0,[](auto &a, auto &b){return a + b.first;});
```

As for me I would initialize it with integer literal of type `long long int`. For example

```
cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0ll,[](auto &a, auto &b){return a +b.first;});
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::accumulate` iterates over each element and calls the supplied function with the current element and the current value of the accumulator.

The accumulator has type `int`, not `pair<int, int>` so you need to fix your lambda function to accept the right argument types.